# Azure function returning 401 for AAD auth

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I am working on Azure function where I need to implement Azure AD auth for securing its end-points.
I have followed the docs as per link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-configure-with-express-settings

I am able to generate access token from Web app as well as from postman with correct aud but everything I test the function, I am getting 401 .

I tried to set different Allowed token audiences as well

[image]

When acuiring access token I am passing same in scope as well

[image]

I have tried other combination as well. e.g.

```
    api://6d561884-6456-4385-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/user_impersonation
    api://6d561884-6456-4385-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/.default
    6d561884-6456-4385-83b9-f283a85dfa1b/.default
```

Auth is successful even I can see same aud in token and scp as well.

Then why I am still getting 401. before Azure AD auth, using function key.. it was working

Comment: Do not include the scope for allowed audience. Your audience is what you configure in AAD as the API ID URI for an App registration in the Expose an API section.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give API permissions to your app on AAD.

Follow the instructions mentioned in this [blog](https://anupamchand.medium.com/securing-your-function-app-api-using-aad-313b929fc009).

Comment: I followed all the steps, even i can see permission in my token